# Point Spectrum of an operator from orthogonal decomposition

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Suppose I have an operator $ H $ that is self-adjoint and densely defined on  $ L^2 (\mathbb{R} , \mathbb{C}) \times L^2 (\mathbb{R} , \mathbb{C}) $.

Suppose further that $ L^2 (\mathbb{R} , \mathbb{C}) $ is an invariant subspace of $ H $.

Now, suppose that the spectrum of $ H $ consists purely of the point spectrum. I am thinking about the Quantum Harmonic Oscillator, for example.

Suppose further that the restriction of $ H $ onto $  L^2 (\mathbb{R} , \mathbb{C}) \times 0 $ and $  0 \times L^2 (\mathbb{R} , \mathbb{C})  $  has purely simple eigenvalues.

Is it true that the spectrum of $ H $ will be the union of the point spectrum of the restriction? If so, how could one prove it?

**Proof Attempt**

Let $ \lambda \in \sigma(H)= \sigma_p (H) $. Then,there is a $ u=(u_1,u_2) \in L^2 (\mathbb{R} , \mathbb{C})\times L^2 (\mathbb{R} , \mathbb{C})  $ such that
\begin{equation}\label{key}
 Hu= \lambda u.
\end{equation}
Now,
\begin{equation}
 H = \begin{pmatrix}
  H_{11} & 0 \\ 
  0 &  H_{22}.
 \end{pmatrix} 
\end{equation}
for $ H_{11} $, $ H_{22} $ self adjoint operators on $ L^2 (\mathbb{R} , \mathbb{C})  $.

Then,
\begin{align}
 H_{11} u_1 &= \lambda u_1, \\
 H_{22} u_2 &= \lambda u_2.
\end{align}

and so certainly $ \sigma(H) \subset \sigma(H_{11}) \cup \sigma(H_{22}) $.

For the other direction, is it correct to simply take $(u,0)$ and $(0,u)$?

I feel like some form of what I am trying to prove- a statement about reconstructing the spectrum of an operator from its restrictions on invariant subspaces which are orthogonally decomposed- should be a standard proposition or theorem in a Functional analysis textbook, but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is fine. You don't need to restrict the type of the elements of the spectrum, though.

From
$$
H-\lambda I=\begin{bmatrix} H_{11}-\lambda I&0\\0& H_{22}-\lambda I\end{bmatrix}
$$
it is easy to see (proof below) that $H-\lambda I$
is invertible if and only if both $H_{11}-\lambda I$ and $H_{22}-\lambda I$ are. So $$
\rho(H)=\rho(H_{11})\cap \rho(H_{22}),$$
and taking complements you get $$\sigma(H)=\sigma(H_{11})\cup\sigma(H_{22}).$$

---

We want to show that $\begin{bmatrix} X&0\\0& Y\end{bmatrix}$ is invertible if and only if $X$ and $Y$ are.

If $AX=XA=I$ and $BY=YB=I$, then $\begin{bmatrix} A&0\\0& B\end{bmatrix}$ is an inverse. Conversely, if
$$
\begin{bmatrix} X&0\\0& Y\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} A&B\\ C& D\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} A&B\\ C& D\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} X&0\\0& Y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} I&0\\0& I\end{bmatrix},
$$
looking at the diagonal coordinates we get the equalities
$$
XA=AX=I, \qquad YD=DY=I.
$$
So $X,Y$ are invertible.